# why cython compiler failed to recognize the embedded struct?

Tags: python-3.x, cython

```
############################ Fail to Pass Compilation(Case I)
# hello.pxd
cdef extern from "time.h":
    cdef struct timespec:
        uint64_t tv_sec
        uint64_t tv_nsec

# world.pyx
cimport hello

cdef class Info:
    cdef public hello.timespec ts

########################### Fail to Pass Compilation(Case II)
# hello.pxd
cdef extern from "time.h":
    cdef struct timespec:
        uint64_t tv_sec
        uint64_t tv_nsec

# world.pyx
cimport hello
from hello cimport timespec as hello_timespec
cdef class Info:
    cdef public hello_timespec ts    

########################################
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    PyTypeObject *Py_TYPE(obj)
    bint PyMapping_Check(obj)
    object PyErr_Format(exc, const char *format, ...)

@cname("__pyx_convert__from_py_struct__timespec")
cdef timespec __pyx_convert__from_py_struct__timespec(obj) except *:
    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

FromPyStructUtility:11:5: 'timespec' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    bint PyMapping_Check(obj)
    object PyErr_Format(exc, const char *format, ...)

@cname("__pyx_convert__from_py_struct__timespec")
cdef timespec __pyx_convert__from_py_struct__timespec(obj) except *:
    cdef timespec result
        ^
------------------------------------------------------------

FromPyStructUtility:12:9: 'timespec' is not a type identifier


################################### Pass Compilation(Case III)
# hello.pxd
cdef extern from "time.h":
    cdef struct timespec:
        uint64_t tv_sec
        uint64_t tv_nsec

# world.pyx
cimport hello
from hello cimport timespec

cdef class Info:
    cdef public timespec ts
```

Question> Why both case I and case II fail to pass the compilation?

Comment: Looks like this bug - https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1153

Comment: All of them work for me once I've added the line `from libc.stdint cimport uint64_t` to `hello.pxd` (Cython 0.26.1). The autoconversion of struct to Python dict for the 'public' attribute may not do quite what you expect - if you modify the `dict` changes _don't_ propagate back.